# Tracking page/screen views with Flurry Analytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry, flurry-analytics

I just added Flurry to my project and some things are not so clear. As an instance I have `ViewController1` and `ViewController2` that I would like to track, how can I accomplish it? I should just add the below codes into my AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and it's ready? Or I need to set `logAllPageViewsForTarget:` in each view controller's `viewWillAppear:`?

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   [Flurry startSession:@"sampleID"];

    UIViewController *viewController1 =
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIDofViewController1"];

    UIViewController *viewController2 =
    [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardIDofViewController2"];


    [Flurry logAllPageViewsForTarget:viewController1];
    [Flurry logAllPageViewsForTarget:viewController2];

return yes;
}
```

When do I need to call `stopLogPageViewsForTarget:`? It's needed always when the user closes the app, or what is it's function in practice?

Actually I'm using `logAllPageViewsForTarget:` in my `AppDelegate`, but in my admin panel when I open the `Page Views` section I get this message:

> You are not currently tracking Page View data. Page View tracking is
>   an optional part of the Flurry SDK that allows you to report the
>   number of page views generated by your users for the purpose of
>   tracking advertising. Since the definition of Page View differs for
>   each application, the Flurry SDK cannot track these for you
>   automatically. Instead, you need to add the appropriate integration
>   points to track page views as they pertain to your application.

Am I missed something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `logAllPageViewsForTarget:(id)` doesn't track specific view count.

From [Flurry Docs](http://flurrydev.github.io/FlurryiOSSDK6xAPI/interface_flurry.html#ad8222c3e2257fb8aa22e9c93aa465ca6):

> This method increments the page view count for a session based on traversing a UINavigationController or UITabBarController. The page view count is only a counter for the number of transitions in your app. It does not associate a name with the page count. To associate a name with a count of occurences see logEvent:.

Therefore, if you want you want to track specific page view counts for specific view controllers you will have to use Flurry events.

For example:

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"VC1_Viewed"];
```

Check out [Flurry Events](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/events/ios/) for detailed info.

Comment: I checked also your update, so it's much cleaner now. So the point is that I just need to pass a string (which names the event)  to the `logEvent:` method in every `viewWillAppear` where I want to track page views? For example everytime when the user reaches the VC where I implemented `[Flurry logEvent:@"VC1_Viewed"];` one "page view" will be counted? That's all?

Comment: There is a bunch of metrics you can see regarding the events (per session, unique users, etc. see: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/lexicon/eventreporting/